# Get value of dropdown in form_open before form submit

Tags: codeigniter

I was testing some features of CI. And stuck here.

**How to receive Selected Value from dropdown in Codeigniter to pass into Controller?**

```
            $options = array(
                ''          => 'Display All',
                '1'         => 'Display English',
                '2'         => 'Display Pashto',
                '3'         => 'Display abc',
                '4'         => 'Display cde',
                '5'         => 'Display efg' );
            $attributes = array(
                'id'    => 'rating',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            );

            echo form_dropdown('rating', $options, 'Display All', $attributes);

            // $key = $this->input->post('rating');
            // $value = $options[$key];

            echo form_open(base_url("lang/display/" . $options)) ;
            echo form_error('rating');
```

Like if someone select: `Display English` from `dropdown` so when I submit the form/Press button, My Controller will receive variable `1` or my URL looks like this: 
`..baseurl../lang/display/1`

Any help would be really appreciated.

PS: The dropdown without `{$options}` in `echo form_open(base_url("lang/display/" . $options));` is working. I tried everything but didn't came up with solution.

**EDIT:**

I can receive value of `$options` after form submit, but I came to know we cannot receive value of `$options` before form submit. What I really want is value of  `$options` when click on button to show/append it to URL so that I can copy and paste that URL anywhere I want.

Comment: you can't get the value without submitting the form first. see my answer below.

Comment: @curiosity Hi, Thank You very much for the beautiful and easy to understand answer. But the problem is may be I wasn't clear about my problem, I can get value in my controller after submitting my form as `$option = $this->input->post('rating');` and even I can pass to `$config['base_url'] = base_url("lang/display/{$option}");` for pagination purpose. But the problem is I want to get it as it displays in URL `echo form_open(base_url("lang/display/" . $options)`. So that I can copy link for someone and he/she can see if these are specific post of `English`, `Pashto` or other languages.

Comment: don't put a wild card on your base url. if you want, you can set up it routes.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to get the value of data from a `dropdown` you don't need to pass the variable `$options` to your form action.

if you need to display the selected value from `dropdown`. you need to do it this way.

```
echo $this->input->post('rating');
```

put that to your success page.

i create an example and i hope it will be useful for you to understand the basics from it.

```
function drop()
    {
        echo form_open('forms/get_val', 'class="email" id="myform"'); //replace it to your controller name and function name
        $options = array(
                'small'         => 'Small Shirt',
                'med'           => 'Medium Shirt',
                'large'         => 'Large Shirt',
                'xlarge'        => 'Extra Large Shirt',
        ); //setting up an option for dropdown

        $shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large'); //put this as a 3rd param to set dropdown selected as listed.
        echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options); //you can add it here the $shirt_on_sale

        echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!'); //submit button
    }

function get_val() //success page
{
    echo $this->input->post('shirts'); //display the selected value.
}
```

i have a controller named **Forms** You can rename that to your controller named **Lang**.

Hope that helps... let me know the result.

Comment: Hi Sir, I have updated my question. Sorry if I was not clear at my first post. I think I need JavaScript to achieve this task. Agree?

Comment: yeah.. much better to use it.